# Webpack production build styles do not appear

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

EDIT: okay, i fixed the problem with my styles by correcting my server file. I had forgotten to update the static resources path. however, I am still having a problem. My javascript is still not firing correctly.[image]

i have output rules defined in my config files for both production and development environments......but clearly i made a mistake somewhere along the line

[image]okay, before I post this I just want to say that I'm struggling pretty hard with webpack. I'm about 6 to 8 months into my training as a front end developer, so I'm already bursting at the seams with new languages and technologies, and this recent journey through the world of build tools may have been more than I can bear.

I'm about to ask some questions, forgive me if they are stupid.

I'm struggling to understand why, currently, my production and development builds are not behaving the same. when i run my dev build, all my styles and js work correctly, however when i run my production build, none of my styles or js work. The dist folder is populated with all the expected bundled files (all my minified css and js is there) and all of the paths in the index.html that is generated seem to point to the correct places in the dist folder.....I'm posting a link to the github repo below.

Looking for any tips or clues. please feel free to ask for more info, I don't really have the first idea of where to start looking (that I haven't already checked) for the cause. the course material i'm consuming online about webpack was pretty poor in my opinion......

https://github.com/Funkh0user/nlp-project

Comment: When you are inspecting with developer tools what do you see in console and network tab? Could you post them too?

Comment: yeah one second....okay there, edited my original post. sorry for my ignorance, i thought I knew a thing or two about web development then I started using webpack......

Comment: "Every expert was once a beginner" You are doing fine :)
The issue with your scripts could be the same, seems like your javascript files are not being loaded because it is not served, at least the service worker is not.

Comment: From what I see, you forgot in the production version about `output: {libraryTarget: 'var', library: 'Client'},` ;) You don't need the filename: "./index.html" entry in HtmlWebpackPlugin because template is called index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright. I determined exactly what my problems were.

1. as noted earlier in the thread, I needed to update my server to reflex my static resources being located in the /dist folder.
2. the js problem turned out to be that I had used qoutes in the regex in the loader rules.

Solved. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is not easy I admit you have to learn a lot to solve many problems :)

Below is a more optimal version of your webpack. I recommend using the `webpack-merge` plugin or, as I will describe in small applications, one file for the dev and prod versions, then you will bypass errors related to the fact that you have to remember to complete the dev and prod versions.

Instead of two dev/prod files, create one `webpack.config.js`

At first it needs to be modified **package.js**

```js
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node src/server/index.js",
  "build-prod": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production",
  "build-dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --mode development --open"
},
```

And now the most important part of **webpack.config.js**

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

function prodPlugin(plugin, mode) {
  return mode ? plugin : () => {};
}

module.exports = (env, {
  mode
}) => {
  const inDev = mode === 'development';
  return {
    mode: inDev ? 'development' : 'production',
    devtool: inDev ? 'source-map' : 'none',
    entry: "./src/client/index.js",
    output: {
      libraryTarget: 'var',
      library: 'Client'
    },
    optimization: inDev ? {} : {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({}),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({})
      ]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
          test: '/.js$/',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            inDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            'css-loader',
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/client/views/index.html",
      }),
      prodPlugin(
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
          // Simulate the removal of files
          dry: true,
          // Write Logs to Console
          verbose: true,
          // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
          cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
          protectWebpackAssets: false
        }),
        mode
      ),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css"
      }),
      prodPlugin(
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW(),
        mode
      )
    ]
  }
}
```

if you use vscode I recommend using this [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) to open generated builds.

Comment: thank you all. as soon as i get home i will try to fix my js issue and i'll mark the answer that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack dev build is working, because the `webpack-dev-server` is launched on `8080` port. All `CSS` styles are inserted inline in `<head>` tag and you can enjoy liveReload.

Production build is not working because of `Express` config, change your config to provided:

```
var path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const mockAPIResponse = require('./mockAPI.js')
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('src/client'));
app.use(cors());

// designates what port the app will listen to for incoming requests
app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log('Example app server listening on port 8081!');
})

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send(mockAPIResponse);
})
```

Was added the line `app.use(express.static('dist'));`. Happened static serving of pages in output `dist` folder, previously you just threw the `index.html` file with incorrect imports.

Before applying the changes, run production build and open `index.html` file in browser by clicking and reconsider, that styles are working correctly.

In short: wrong `Express` setup, `dist` folder should be public

Comment: this solution works for my styles but my js is still malfunctioning. thank you for your response by the way. did you leave the first app.use statement in the file purposefully ?

Comment: At first forgot to remove, second thought was that `express` can serve two static folders, so the line was left.